# loop condition return value in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am creating a procedure in pl.sql and I want the return is true and false with the condition if the colums end_date is less then today and return false if then today then return true on each record. This is my procedure code

```
    create or replace procedure GET_REGIS_LIMIT(V_CURSOR out SYS_REFCURSOR) is
PR_END_DATE DATE;
begin
  BEGIN
  FOR myDATE in(SELECT END_DATE INTO PR_END_DATE FROM REGISTER_LIMIT T WHERE T.STATUS='U') 
  LOOP
    PR_END_DATE:=myDATE.END_DATE;
    OPEN V_CURSOR FOR
    SELECT T.*, (SELECT CASE WHEN PR_END_DATE > SYSDATE THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END  FROM DUAL END) RESULTS
    FROM REGISTER_LIMIT T WHERE T.STATUS='U';
  END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN  -- catches all 'no data found' errors
      OPEN V_CURSOR FOR
    SELECT 'EMPTY' RESULTS FROM DUAL  ; 
     end;

end GET_REGIS_LIMIT;
```

[image]

The column i mark should return **true** but all of them are return **false** or it depends on the last row

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a loop. Just open a ref cursor which returns the result set you need.

````
create or replace procedure get_regis_limit(v_cursor out sys_refcursor) is
begin
  open v_cursor for
    select t.*
           , case when end_date > sysdate then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end  as results
    from register_limit t 
    where t.status='u';
end get_regis_limit;```
````